# Revoking an app in Google Play Store - can the same name/title be used again?

Tags: google-play, google-play-games

Due to a well known and quite often discussed "keystore-signing-problem" I need to rebuild my app from scratch again in Google Play Store.

However I wonder: In case the "old" app will be disabled - can I use the same name for the "new" app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two important things you need to pay attention to are [the signing hash and the package name](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings). You can only have a single app published per combination of SHA1 hash/package name. All other fields (title, app name, etc) and configuration within your Android app can be set to whatever you want and you should have no trouble with conflicts.